# XSLT Intellisense in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xslt, intellisense

I have an XML file which in addition to it's standard XML schema allows the use of XSLT.

I am including the correct namespace for XSLT (xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform") however I am not receiving Intellisense for XSLT when I start typing xsl: tags.

Is it possible to turn this on? When I edit XSLT files it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Xml editor does support the standard xsl intellisense but it will strictly apply the schema.  Hence you first need to enter a `<xsl:stylesheet>` and start adding children to it before you will see any xsl options.  This is because all other other xsl elements need be children of either the xsl:stylesheet element or some other xsl element.

Comment: Makes sense, if I were to define a schema for my XML document which specified xsl:choose for example being available within certain tags would that be allowed?

Comment: @Craig: Dunno, never tried, have a go and let us know the results.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT Intellisense is a hidden feature of VS 2008. It has to be enabled by setting a Registry key (http://memoryleak.me.uk/2008/11/xslt-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2008.html):

> First, make sure you have the xslt.xsd
>   file in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas folder.
>   If not, copy it from VS2005.
>
> Next, add a new string value to the
>   registry named `XsltIntellisense`
>   under
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\XmlEditor`
>   and set the value to `True`. This will
>   enable some other nice features to the
>   standard tag completion stuff.

This hint came originally from http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000740.html

Comment: I tried it once some time ago and then it worked, although the benefit didn't seem to be too much. Maybe it's no longer working since SP1...